# Proper method of writing pseudo random sequences into binary files?

Tags: implementation, pseudo-random-generator

I am working in Python and created a B.B.S. implementation that outputs a sequence of pseudo random positive integers into a Python list.  I would like to write this data to a binary file and pass it through ENT and Diehard to see how well it does, but I have no idea how to properly do this.

So far I have been writing these pseudo random sequences in python lists into binary files with the `struct` package, but even PRNG's like B.B.S. are horribly failing these tests, so I know I must be writing the data to the file incorrectly.

Would anyone be able to tell me the correct way to write a pseudo random sequence of integers of form `[85285422, 1065539406, 1143357354, 812899410, 796171749, 531684531, 771767949, 527982099, ...]` in a python list into a file for testing with ENT and Dieharder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to write this data to a binary file and pass it through ENT and Diehard to see how well it does

To test how well something does, we must have a definition of "well". For a RNG, that's almost universally: *outputs independent uniformly random elements of some discrete set*. That set is often integers in $[0,m)$ for some $m$. ENT is designed¹ for that with $m=2^8$, thus the set of all the possible bytes. Diehard(er) can test that too, that's what `/dev/urandom` outputs, and it's my suggestion.

---

The question's sequence is as obtained by²: $x_{i+1}\gets{x_i}^2\bmod1232592891$. That's against the security rationale of the [Blum Blum Shub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) generator, which asks that

1. Only a few low-order bits of $x_i$ obtained by $x_{i+1}\gets{x_i}^2\bmod n$ should be output.
2. $n$ is a hard to factor integer³, implying that $n$ has at least 500 bits and it factors at least 150 bits for even mild hardness.

We can initially ignore the second issue. For the first, we can take *few* as 8 bits, that is reduce each number produced modulo 256, before writing each result as an individual byte in a file opened in binary mode with [open](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open). Or take it as 1 bit, reducing modulo 2 and grouping 8 consecutive bits in oen byte. In both cases, that's discarding most of the data, but that's a necessity to have a passably random-like sequence.

---

It's interesting to learn how to make a generator that pass ENT and Diehard(er). Importantly, one should realize that **a statistical test can't validate a RNG**, only invalidate it. If such test consistently yields a fail result, then the sequence tested has some serious defect⁴. But if it yields a pass result, that does not validate the cryptographic quality of the sequence. It is plain impossible to do this from the sequence. *What generates the sequence* must be examined.

---

¹ With the caveat that ENT's main test is insensitive to the order of the bytes in its input: it does not even try to assess the "independent" part of "independent uniformly random elements of some discrete set".

² That recurrence predicts the next value all over the sequence. I inferred it form from the question's "B.B.S." and the fact that the output values looked like 10-digit decimal integer with first digit either 1, or 0 and suppressed. I found the modulus by computing $\gcd({x_{i+1}}^2-x_i,\ {x_{i+2}}^2-x_{i+1})$ for various $i$ in the output sequence, then dividing by 2.

³ The modulus $n$ can be public, that's the salient feature in the construction.

⁴ Alternatively, the test was misused or is defective.

Answer (score 0):

Blum Blum Shub requires larger parameters for security than parameters that are typically suggested for factoring (or QR). See [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3456/45690) for references.

The short of it is that there are likely no issues with using `struct`, but that you likely need to use a modulus of $\approx 6800$ bits and extract no more than $5$ bits per iteration to a *concretely* secure PRNG from BBS.