# Rigorous practical pseudorandom generators

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

It is known that existence of pseudorandom generators (PRGs) is [equivalent](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579323) to the existence of one-way functions. In turn, the latter is an open problem.

I am curious if someone developed kind of "practical" PRGs, which are weaker than PRGs in terms of computational indistinguishably to uniform random number generators.

I know of some statistical tests for randomness, but is there any rigorous theory on the subject?

This is a [repost](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391908/practical-pseudorandom-generators) from MO, and I intend to remove the original question.

Comment: Does your definition of a PRG include a cryptographic PRG? If yes, then isn't the answer self evident?

Comment: @PaulUszak I don't get what you mean. CPRG is a PRG, in common terms. And what exactly is self-evident here?

Comment: Sorry, I was too vague. If CPRG = PRG ~ open question, the clearly _practical_ PRGs exist as we use them and are not yet invertible. There's a whole list of "Related" questions adjacent to this one giving rigorous examples. Or am I misunderstanding your meaning?

Comment: @PaulUszak Think you still get me wrong. Perhaps, the word "practical" is misleading. I know that one can construct PRGs, in turn CPRGs, from 1-way functions. The rigor = to show the constructed PRGs are comp. indistinguishable from randomized algorithms. But what can we rigorusly show without conjecturing 1-way functions? There is chaos "PRGs", but they aren't concerned with comp.  indistinguishability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worth mentioning that there is a connection in complexity theory often called "Hardness v Pseudorandomness" that makes this question somewhat difficult.
It may not be surprising that given a strong enough PRG, one can derandomize certain randomized algorithms, i.e. trying to prove $P = BPP$ can be done by giving a provably strong enough pseudorandom generator.

What is perhaps surprising is that this is intimately connected to the existence of hard problems in $NP$.
Specifically, if there is a problem in $NP$ that requires exponentially sized circuits, I believe it implies that $P = BPP$ via the construction of an explicit pseudorandom generator.
Moreover, some form of the reverse holds --- being able to derandomize $P$ (via the construction of a provably good PRG of good enough parameters) leads to circuit lower bounds, which is a notoriously hard subject.
Keywords for this are things like "Nisan-Wigderson PRG", or you can look at [these notes](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eledt/papers/Avi/L1.pdf) for some pointers.

I think (but am fuzzy on the details) that one can generalize the above to other circuit classes as well, i.e. the existence of explicit provably secure PRGs against some circuit class is intimately related to circuit lower bounds against some related circuit class.
As in general most circuit lower bounds we can prove are against fairly restricted models of computation, I would expect that the literature on "rigorous PRGs" is restricted to PRGs that are secure against relatively weak forms of computation.

I don't know a great place that summarizes this all --- I do not myself work in the area, but heard about it from someone who does. Perhaps [their thesis](https://core.ac.uk/display/227481590) would be a good reference, but I'll admit that I have not personally read it.

Comment: @PaulUszak Computationally indistinguishability against some circuit class $\mathcal{C}$ is a formal property, namely that no circuit $C\in\mathcal{C}$ can distinguish between the output of the PRG and a uniformly random string. For certain circuit classes that we cannot prove lower bounds on, the Hardness vs Pseudorandomness paradigm means we also cannot construct provably PRGs (without implicitly also proving lower bounds). For weaker circuit classes that we *do* have strong lower bounds on, there is no such obstacle, and one could construct a PRG that is provably secure against that class.

Comment: The notion of "practically proven" isn't something you can mathematically formalize though, and moreover any such formalization would include "the existence of one-way functions" as something that has been "practically proven" (especially given that universal one-way functions exist). I interpret the asker as asking about the existence of provable "weaker" notions of PRGs, and this exists in precisely "explicit PRGs that are secure against weaker circuit classes".

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is cryptographic strength [given the context stated by the OP, I assume it is] in a PRNG that will be used in practice, then the randomness testing methods can be used to *rule out* generators as being weak, but obviously cannot rigorously demonstrate randomness.

However there are pitfalls in using generators which are based on problems which are assumed to be hard.

In terms of the CSPRNGs, such as Blum-Blum-Shub (BBS), which is the most well-known example, care must be taken that the  extraction rate of "cryptographically strong bits" is not too high compared to the state space of the BBS iteration. The theoretical suggestion is if the iteration is
$$
x_{k+1}=x_k^2 \pmod n,\quad n=pq
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are large primes, one should at most take $O(\log \log n)$ least significant bits of $x_k$ and output them as pseudorandom bits.

This approach is full of pitfalls, however. Firstly, the specification is asymptotic, so what's a reasonable constant to use in front of the $O(\cdot)$ expression? Vanstone and Menezes in an Indocrypt paper suggested not to use more than 1 bit, i.e., just the least significant bit.

More seriously [see the first answer to this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/blum-blum-shub-vs-aes-ctr-or-other-csprngs) in crypto stackexchange for details] it turns out that the security reduction in BBS is so inefficient that maybe *it should not be used at all* in practice:

> Suppose you use BBS with a 768-bit modulus. You've read that 768 bits is enough to make factoring infeasible, so this sounds peachy. You've read that it is safe to extract O(lg n) bits in each iteration; here n = 768, and lg n = 9.58, so you decide to extract 9 bits in each iteration. You use it to generate a pseudorandom stream of 107 bits (about 1MB of pseudorandom data). How much security do you get? Answer: the security proof guarantees security against any adversary that uses at most $2^{-264}$ steps of computation. Yes, this is an utterly ridiculous and useless statement! To put it in plain English, the security proof guarantees absolutely nothing useful at all.

On the other hand if one wanted security against an attack of complexity approximately $2^{100}$ steps (reasonable since $2^{128}$ brute force complexity is standard these days) one would have to choose $n$ of about 6800 bits. This is now more feasible since RSA moduli of 4096 bits are now common.

Notwithstanding this, it is amazing how inefficient the security proof reduction in BBS is. One can demonstrate that  breaking BBS and is $1054 n^3$ times faster than factoring the BBS modulus $n.$

So practical CSPRNG security is a moving target, very dependent on algorithmic developments, even in the case of generators designed by using hard problems.

Comment: This is not rigorous